# How to connect to codeanywhere ide by secure shell?

Tags: ssh, terminal

I installed the Secure Shell extension for chrome on windows. Can anyone please tell me how to connect to my devbox in codeanywhere using this secure shell extension?

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Chrome Secure Shell to connect to your CodeAnywhere container, you will need:

- The hostname and port for your container. (You can find that by right-clicking your container, choosing Info, and looking for the SSH access information.)
- The username will be cabox. [[1](http://docs.codeanywhere.com/connections/container.html)]

You will also need both a private and a public key in order to import an identity into Chrome Secure Shell. [[2](http://www.mattburns.co.uk/blog/2012/11/15/connecting-to-ec2-from-chromes-secure-shell-using-only-a-pem-file/)]

- Your container's private key is stored in `/home/cabox/.ssh/id_rsa` and the public key is stored in `/home/cabox/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

  - Since the `/home/cabox/.ssh/` folder is not visible in the left-hand menu, open an SSH terminal to your container. (Right-click your container, then choose SSH Terminal.)
  - At the prompt, type `cp ../.ssh/id_rsa .` to copy the private key to the workspace folder.
  - At the prompt, type `cp ../.ssh/id_rsa.pub .` to copy the public key to the workspace folder.
  - Right-click your container, and click Refresh to refresh the list of files
  - Download the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files (which should now be visible on the left-hand menu) by right-clicking and choosing Download

In Chrome Secure Shell,

- Give the connection a name
- Use the username cabox
- Fill out the hostname and port
- Next to Identity, click Import. When file selection screen opens, choose **both** the `id_rsa` and the `id_rsa.pub` files
- Once the Identity has been imported, you should be able to connect to your CodeAnywhere container.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no idea about ssh extension on chrome, but firstly you have to install a ssh server on your devbox. If your devbox is ubuntu you should try like this from your codeanywhere ssh terminal:

```
    sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

After that check your ip on your devbox machine by:

```
    ifconfig
```

command. Finnaly connect to your devbox from your chrome extension ssh by:

```
    ssh yourUsernameFromDevbox@devboxIP
```

After that you just insert your devbox machine password and voila.